# C# List of inherited classes

Tags: c#, list, inheritance

I have the following classes:

```
public class BaseClass() {}
public class Class1 : BaseClass {}
public class Class2 : BaseClass {}

public class BaseClassList : List<BaseClass> {}
public class Class1List : List<Class1> {}
public class Class2List : List<Class2> {}
```

The data is in JSON format are is loaded as a list of BaseClass objects. Once loaded and want to populate the specific lists with the relevant objects:

```
public void Setup()
{
    Class1List list1 = new Class1List();

    var query = from x in BaseClassList
                where x.Type = MyType.Class1
                select x;

    list1.AddRange(query);
}
```

However AddRange doesn't compile because I'm trying to added BaseClass objects to a Class1 list.

How can I successfully add the inherited classes?

Comment: `BaseClassList` is the name of a type - or do you have some property of that type too? It's also not clear why you have subclasses of `List<T>` at all - that's usually not a great idea, IME.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code snippet,

```
public void Setup()
{
  Class1List list1 = new Class1List();

  var query = from x in BaseClassList
            where x.GetType() == typeof(Class1)
            select x as Class1;

  list1.AddRange(query);
}
```

The as operator casts your type `BaseClass`to type `Class1`

Reference: [MSDN as Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx)

As mentioned in a comment, you can do it a little bit more save with this snippet:

```
public void Setup()
{
  Class1List list1 = new Class1List();

  var query = from x in BaseClassList
        where x.GetType() == typeof(Class1)
        select x;

   foreach(var item in query){
      var temp = item as Class1;
      if(temp  != null)
         list1.Add(temp);
   }
}
```

After casting to Class1 you can check for null, as the `as`operator returns null if unable to cast. I would prefer to make a type compare with `where x.GetType() == typeof(Class1)`

Comment: Personally I'd use a cast rather than `as` - do you really want it to silently proceed (and add a `null` reference) if there's a non-Class1 element with a `Type` property of `MyType.Class1`?

Comment: The casting is always returning a null

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono why does it?

Comment: don't know. temp is always null.

Comment: So the objects are not of type `Class1`. What is `MyType.Class1` ? Seems like a enum?!

Comment: the objects are of type Class1 which inherits BaseClass. MyType.Class1 is just an enum to filter out objects when adding to specific lists.

Comment: Are you sure they are of type `Class1`? Did you debug and looked into the list at a breakpoint? I've reproduced a example with your classes but without the enum. I used `where x.GetType() == typeof(Class1)`. My solution worked.